# What does d(0, P) notation mean?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

In the solution of this example, the author uses the following: $$d(0, P)=|r|$$

But what does that notation mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads: "*the distance* (denoted by $d$) *from the origin* (denoted by $O$) *to the point $P$ is $|r|$*"

Comment: Thanks. It makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

$o$ is the origin, $P$ is a point, $d$ is the distance, so "distance between the origin and your particle".